# How do I disable the pop-up?

Tags: gnome, 13.10

How I can disable the pop up that appears when I'm hovering over applications?
Example"

[image]

Comment: Is that Ubuntu GNOME Remix?

Comment: what do you mean?Gnome 3.5 i guess

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Err... I have ubuntu 13.04 and Gnome 3.6, that's why